# How do I iteratively copy logs from the local drive to a network share?

Tags: python, logging, copying, iteration

I'm new to Python. I'm running version 3.3. I'd like to iteratively copy all wildcard named folders and files from the C drive to a network share. Wildcard named folders are called "Test_1", "Test_2", etc. with folders containing the same named folder, "Pass". The files in "Pass" end with .log. I do NOT want to copy the .log files in the Fail folder. So, I have this:

```
C:\Test_1\Pass\a.log
C:\Test_1\Fail\a.log
C:\Test_1\Pass\b.log
C:\Test_1\Fail\b.log
C:\Test_2\Pass\y.log
C:\Test_2\Fail\y.log
C:\Test_2\Pass\z.log
C:\Test_2\Fail\z.log
```

but only want to copy

```
C:\Test_1\Pass\a.log
C:\Test_1\Pass\b.log
C:\Test_2\Pass\y.log
C:\Test_2\Pass\z.log
```

to:

```
\\share\Test_1\Pass\a.log
\\share\Test_1\Pass\b.log
\\share\Test_2\Pass\y.log
\\share\Test_2\Pass\z.log'
```

The following code works but I don't want to copy tons of procedural code.  I'd like to make it object oriented.

```
import shutil, os
from shutil import copytree
def main():
    source = ("C:\\Test_1\\Pass\\")
    destination = ("\\\\share\\Test_1\\Pass\\")
    if os.path.exists ("C:\\Test_1\\Pass\\"):
        shutil.copytree (source, destination)
        print ('Congratulations!  Copy was successfully completed!')
    else:
        print ('There is no Actual folder in %source.')
main()
```

Also, I noticed it is not printing the "else" print statement when the os path does not exist. How do I accomplish this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a perfect example but you could do this:

```
import glob, os, shutil

#root directory
start_dir = 'C:\\'

def copy_to_remote(local_folders, remote_path):
    if os.path.exists(remote_path):    
        for source in local_folders:
            # source currently has start_dir at start. Strip it and add remote path
            dest = os.path.join(remote_path, source.lstrip(start_dir))
            try:
                shutil.copytree(source, dest)
                print ('Congratulations!  Copy was successfully completed!')
            except FileExistsError as fe_err:
                print(fe_err)
            except PermissionError as pe_err:
                print(pe_err)
    else:
        print('{} - does not exist'.format(remote_path))



# Find all directories that start start_dir\Test_ and have subdirectory Pass
dir_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(start_dir, 'Test_*\\Pass'))
if dir_list:
    copy_to_remote(dir_list, '\\\\Share\\' )
```

Documentation for `glob` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob).

Comment: Just a few minor tweaks.  That did it!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
def remotecopy(local, remote)
    if os.path.exists(local):
        shutil.copytree (local, remote)
        print ('Congratulations!  Copy was successfully completed!')
    else:
        print ('There is no Actual folder in %local.')
```

Then just remotecopy("C:\Local\Whatever", "C:\Remote\Whatever")